# How to apply CSS style only to div and not the before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have a html page which has a div looking like this:

```
<div class="get-this"> blah blah </div>
```

I have a before pseudoelement on the div and I am trying to apply CSS style only to the div which will not be applicable to the pseudo element.

```
.get-this:not(::before) {
  padding-top:2px;
}
```

The style is applied to the entire div. IS it possible to restrict the style only to the div and not the pseudo element?

Comment: what style you are trying to apply

Comment: the padding-top style?

Comment: share your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735496/can-css-not-selector-target-before-and-after-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a straightforward use of the cascade.

The CSS cascade is intended to enable you to apply general styles to more general selectors and overriding styles to more specific selectors.

Hence:

```
.get-this {
  padding-top:2px;
}

.get-this::before {
  padding-top:0;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.paragraph-one {
color: red;
}

.paragraph-two {
color: blue;
}

.paragraph-one::before {
content: 'Paragraph One: ';
}

.paragraph-two::before {
content: 'Paragraph Two: ';
color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph-one">This is paragraph one. It is red.</p>
<p class="paragraph-two">This is paragraph two. It is blue.</p>
<p>The <code>::before</code> pseudo-element preceding Paragraph Two <em>isn't the same color</em> as the rest of Paragraph Two, because, further down the cascade, an overriding style has been declared for the more specific <code>.paragraph-two::before</code> selector.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already applied all of your div element to have before or after css they would require you to type content: ""; in order to show style applied to DOM:before or DOM:after

Which means if you set content to none it won't show that.
to overwrite your div style you can simply do

```
.get-this:before {
    content: none;
}
```

But I would avoid applying before or after properties to all of your div element of your application. div element is often used on many situation, therefore you will run into problem you are now facing on every div element. which mean writing css to overwrite css. that's just not a good practice in most of case.

Also if your DOM element that has before, after its position is related with parent DOM, that being said, if your DOM's padding, margin, positioning, size changes will effect to before or after of that DOM