# Select Elements that don't have ::before OR ::after

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-awesome

I want to style all texts in a page with a font except for **Font Icons** (**Font Awesome**) which don't have any common class. So I need to select elements in one of these ways:

1. Elements that don't have **::before** OR **::after**
2. Elements that don't have the **content** style

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't....there is **NO** CSS selector for elements with or without a specific property or pseudo-element.

Comment: You need JavaScript for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your icons are using 'fa' or some other unified class, you could use `not:`

Eg:

```
span:not(.fa) {
 /* styling */
}
```

Comment: I edited my question because all of them don't have any common class. At least it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, then I don't think it's possible without javascript. The `:not` selector doesn't work with `:before` etc. Sorry I couldn't help more - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735496/can-css-not-selector-target-before-and-after-selectors