# How to change an element's font-family without affecting it's ::before or ::after?

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

A lot of sites use the `::before` selector on an element to load icons via a client-downloaded font file, e.g.

```
div {
    font: 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}

div::before {
    content: "\f1c8";
}
```

Unfortunately the following rule also applies to the element's `::before` pseudo-element, which breaks the icon display:

```
div {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```

It's *not* possible to `:not(::before)` [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735496/can-css-not-selector-target-before-and-after-selectors), so how would you go about targeting an element, but not it's `::before`?

This worked decently, but it misses the text (if any) inside the element:

```
div:not([class*="fa-"]) {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```

It may not even be possible. No JavaScript, please.

Comment: target the pseudo element to explicitly define its font

Comment: You can define the element's font directly with the font family Font Awesome provides, something like this: `font-family: "Font Awesome 5;` haven't used Font Awesome in a while so I don't the exact declaration but something along those lines.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Post your answer below, this worked: `::before{font-family: FontAwesome}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Termani's help above, this is how I solved the problem of injecting my preferred font into websites while doing minimal damage to most site's icons loaded via webfont files:

```
::before, ::after {
    font-family: FontAwesome, "Font Awesome", "Font Awesome 5 Pro",
    "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Material Icons", "Material-Design-Iconic-Font",
    Flaticon, "CBSi Fantasy icomoon", CBSi_Fantasy_icomoon, icon-moon,
    icomoon, ui-icons, icons, NewYorkIcons, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Without doubt there are other `font-family` names that developers use, so the list will grow as I stumble upon them.

I'll update this answer if I find a better solution.

Comment: So, basically my solution :P

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without then again overwriting the before and after again

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

Or you could just use the icon in another element entirely.

```html
<span class="fa-something"></span>
<span>Text here</span>
```

And a s a sidenote :)
Please use textelements for text, not divs (and span is also not a text element, it simply is an inline element without any semantic information)

Comment: I appreciate the info. Note that I am not the author of the sites that need modification. My css edits are injected in my client via userCSS.